# Going from NavigationController to TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So... I've got a ViewController that's being pushed onto a NavigationController.  In interface builder I create a separate ViewController and Embed it into a TabBarController and it looks good in Interface Builder.

In my app, I'm trying to go from one of the ViewControllers in my NavigationView to the ViewController in the TabBarController.  How would I do this the correct way?  I can't just push the view onto the NavigationController, because the tab bar at the bottom won't show up.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're operating with the UINavigationController and UITabBarController in a backwards order to recommended best-practice.

Unless something has changed in the last year or two (which may have happened) the UINavigationController should never have a UITabBarController pushed onto it. If you are using a UITabBarController in your app, it should be the window.rootViewController, and the navigation controller being member of the UITabBarController's viewControllers array.

> I'm trying to go from one of the ViewControllers in my NavigationView
>   to the ViewController in the TabBarController. How would I do this the
>   correct way?

In that structure, you'd assign your destination view controller as another element of the viewControllers array.  Then, in my style, I'd send a NSNotification something like "LaunchOtherViewController" from your first view controller, and thus you have no need for the first view controller to know about the tab bar controller or second view controller.  Then have some class that knows about the second view controller receive that notification, and update the selectedIndex of the UITabBarController to that of the second, destination view controller.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So, would it be good practice to do this?:

UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
                                               window.rootViewController = myTabBarController;

Comment: @DavidB That's the idea. That code is getting the window as if there is no window ivar already available such as in the UIApplicationDelegate subclass, usually defined in a xib file with an IBOutlet.  So I wonder, are you assigning window.rootViewController = myTabBarController from somewhere else in your app, and is it *not* at launch?

Comment: Well, here's what I'm doing:  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                                            DriverHomeViewController *createdViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"driverHome"];
                                                UITabBarController *bar = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
              window.rootViewController = bar;
[bar presentViewController:createdViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: How would I go about accessing the window ivar from the AppDelagte?

Comment: Also, I'm now getting this error after the transition:  Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x10fed2b70>.

Comment: I haven't really used storyboards since they were created. They've always felt too bulky to me. The way of nib/xib files, a traditional MainWindow.xib would have File's Owner be UIApplication. Delegate would be an instantiated object declared within the xib, implementing UIApplicationDelegate protocol. That object would also have an IBOutlet "window" property.  This detail is what I'm comfortable with, although it's a few years old and probably not very relevant since you're using a storyboard.  Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Actually, I don't even use a MainWindow.xib file, usually. I setup/instantiate a lot of my UI from code.  The most I've done since iOS 5 is adopt ARC in newer projects.  I still don't use autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the TabBarController onto the view.  You may need to set the selected view controller of the tab bar, but it's important the tab bar controller be actually pushed onto the navigation stack (or presented modally).

Comment: Is it just me, or does this go against the apple HIG?  Or some other recommended interaction between UITabBarController and UINavigationController.  I haven't worked with the stock view controllers for a number of years, but there was a suggestion to not put a UITabBarController within a UINavigationController, but the opposite was recommended.

Comment: In short, yes.  A TabBarController should always be the root view controller, which means it should either be the root view of the window, or it should be presented modally.  But neither Xcode nor Cocoa prevent you from doing this.  I don't know for sure whether or not an app that does this would pass app-store review, but he's not necessarily writing an app store app.  Either way, this comment is probably more appropriate on the question, rather than on my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the commendation.  I have also posted the same idea with more detail as an answer :)